Powershell : How do I pass parameter from command line to a function
test.psm1
function test{
Param(
    
    [string]$name,
    [string]$Id
    )
  
echo “Your name is $name”
    
echo “Your Id is $Id”
}
Export-ModuleMember -Function test

test1.ps1
Import-Module ".\WindowsPowerShell\modules\test.psm1" -Verbose -Force
test($name, $Id)

Command passed on CMD line :

.\test1.ps1 -name "joke" -Id 3

O/P :

Your name is   Your Id is

I want the output to be :

Your name is Joke
Your Id is 3


As an aside: avoid surrounding strings with smart quotes

You've got two problems:

Your test.ps1 doesn't declare any parameters so the $name and $id variables don't have values in test.ps1

If you want to pass multiple parameters to a function you use the format test $name $id or test -name $name -id $id, not test($name, $Id) - your version is equivalent to test -name @($name, $id) -id $null, that is, the brackets define an array value as a single parameter rather than enclose a list of parameters. See this question amongst several other similar ones with the same issue: PowerShell function parameters syntax


Fixed versions of files:
test.psm1
function test
{
    param(
        [string] $name,
        [string] $Id
    )

    echo "Your name is $name"
    echo "Your Id is $Id"
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function test

test.ps1
param(
    $name,
    $id
)

Import-Module ".\test.psm1" -Verbose -Force

test -name $name -id $Id

and you can then invoke it on the commandline as:
powershell .\test.ps1 -name "joke" -id 3

to get the output
Your name is joke
Your Id is 3


To pass your arguments correctly, you don't have to specify the parameters in the command. so it's going to be .\test1.ps1 joke 3
Edit: You can also check this link here, it explains passing arguments to a Shell script https://tecadmin.net/pass-command-line-arguments-in-shell-script/
